# Set CSliderCtrl to move in 10 unit intervals

Tags: mfc

I have a `CSliderCtrl` and I set it up like this:

```
m_sliderServerTimeout.SetRange(10, 600);
```

I have an event handler:

```
void COtherSettingsEmailInfoPage::OnHScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
{
    if (pScrollBar->GetDlgCtrlID() == IDC_SLIDER)
    {
        UpdateServerTimeoutDescription();
    }

    CMFCPropertyPage::OnHScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);
}
```

Works fine but I want the slider to move in 10 unit intervals.

How?

## Update

I tried using `SetLineSize` and `SetPageSize` but they don't apply to when the slider is dragged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the slider metric you want. So just use 1/10th in the range of the values.

```
m_sliderServerTimeout.SetRange(1, 60);
```

And finally when you want to use the data, just scale the set value by *10.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a [`Trackbar Control Message`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486075(v=vs.85).aspx) to handle this.

One option is to override `OnHScroll` manually. Watch for `SB_THUMBTRACK` message and save the value for `nPos`. When `SB_ENDSCROLL` is called, use `CSliderCtrl::SetPos` to set to the desired value. Example:

```
void CMyDialog::OnHScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
{
    CDialog::OnHScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);

    static int track = -1;
    if(nSBCode == SB_THUMBTRACK)
        track = nPos;

    if(nSBCode == SB_ENDSCROLL && track >= 0)
    {
        m_sliderServerTimeout.SetPos(10 * int(track / 10));
        track = -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have accepted the other answer though as overall it is simpler to implement. But thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted this and the tool-tip to work as well.  I had to come up with the following:

Header:

```
#pragma once


// CStepSliderCtrl

class CStepSliderCtrl : public CSliderCtrl
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CStepSliderCtrl)

public:
    CStepSliderCtrl();
    virtual ~CStepSliderCtrl();

protected:
    int m_nStart=0;
    uint32_t m_nStep=0;
    CString m_strFmt;

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    afx_msg BOOL OnTtnNeedText(UINT id, NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult);
    void SetStepRange(int min, int max, uint32_t step, const TCHAR *fmt=NULL);
    int GetStepPos();
    void SetStepPos(int pos);
};
```

C++ Module:

```
// CStepSliderCtrl.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CStepSliderCtrl.h"

// CStepSliderCtrl

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CStepSliderCtrl, CSliderCtrl)

CStepSliderCtrl::CStepSliderCtrl()
{

}

CStepSliderCtrl::~CStepSliderCtrl()
{
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CStepSliderCtrl, CSliderCtrl)
    ON_NOTIFY_EX(TTN_NEEDTEXT, 0, &OnTtnNeedText)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()



// CStepSliderCtrl message handlers

void CStepSliderCtrl::SetStepRange(int min, int max, uint32_t step, const TCHAR *fmt)
{
  m_nStart=min;
  m_nStep=step;
  m_strFmt=fmt;

  SetRange(0, (max-min)/step);
}

int CStepSliderCtrl::GetStepPos()
{
  return m_nStart+(GetPos()*m_nStep);
}
   
void CStepSliderCtrl::SetStepPos(int pos)
{
  SetPos((pos-m_nStart)/m_nStep);
}

BOOL CStepSliderCtrl::OnTtnNeedText(UINT id, NMHDR* pnmhdr, LRESULT* presult)
{
  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(id);

  NMTTDISPINFO* pttt = (NMTTDISPINFO*)pnmhdr;

  _stprintf_s(pttt->szText, _countof(pttt->szText), m_strFmt.IsEmpty() ? _T("%i") : m_strFmt, GetStepPos());
  pttt->hinst = AfxGetResourceHandle();

  *presult = 0;
  return TRUE;
}
```

Use `SetStepRange()` instead of `SetRange()`, `GetStepPos()` instead of `GetPos()` and `SetStepPos()` instead of `SetPos()`